# local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final 3

Tags: java, javafx

I get the error message: "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"

This error refers to:

```
MyTreeItem LeftRootItem = (MyTreeItem) treeViewLeft.getRoot();
```

What is my mistake. And why this error is not coming similar to "treeViewRight"?

```
addAttribute.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        TreeView treeViewLeft = new TreeView ();
        treeViewLeft.setShowRoot(false);
        treeViewLeft.setRoot(new MyTreeItem ("root"));
        treeViewLeft.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
        TreeView treeViewRight;
        Button button = new Button ("<<");
        HBox hBox = new HBox ();
        DBConnect.dbconnect();
        treeViewRight = DB.loadAttributeClasses();
        treeViewLeft = DB.getAttributesfromClassorProduct(selectedItem.getClassID());
        treeViewRight.setShowRoot(false);
        treeViewRight.getRoot().setExpanded(true);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(treeViewLeft, button, treeViewRight);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hBox);

        Stage attributeSelect = new Stage ();
        attributeSelect.setTitle("Hello World!");
        attributeSelect.setScene(scene);
        attributeSelect.show();     

        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                MyTreeItem rightItem = (MyTreeItem) treeViewRight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                DB.setProdClassAttr(selectedItem.getClassID(), rightItem.getClassID(), selectedItem.getType());

                rightItem.getParent().getChildren().remove(rightItem);
                MyTreeItem LeftRootItem = (MyTreeItem) treeViewLeft.getRoot();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign two different `TreeView`s to `treeViewLeft`.

Your 4th line is

```
TreeView treeViewLeft = new TreeView ();
```

and a few lines further down you assign a new value to `treeViewLeft`:

```
treeViewLeft = DB.getAttributesfromClassorProduct(selectedItem.getClassID());
```

That is not allowed if you want to reference `treeViewLeft` from the buttons `onAction` handler.

You only assign a value to `treeViewRight` once, and this is allowed.